# Image Getting cut on Border with SimpleDraweeView android

Tags: android, fresco

[![enter image description here][1]][1]This is my SimpleDraeeViwe after image load image is not loading as full, means its covering full width of image view but image getting cut on left and right side.
Also tried with android:adjustViewBounds = true

```
<com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
                android:id="@+id/image_mint"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minHeight="100dp"
                fresco:actualImageScaleType="fitCenter"
                fresco:viewAspectRatio="1.33"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Comment: add :Fresco.initialize(this); to your Application class.

Comment: yes I initialized already that why its laoding images, otherwise it will cras the app.

Answer (score 0):

```
try this

    <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
                    android:id="@+id/image_mint"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    fresco:actualImageScaleType="fitCenter"
                     />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the correct scale type, in your case `centerCrop`:

```
<com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
            android:id="@+id/image_mint"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="100dp"
            fresco:actualImageScaleType="centerCrop"
            fresco:viewAspectRatio="1.33"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

See also http://frescolib.org/docs/scaling.html

Comment: I want image should be fit to mobile width and should not but from left and right side.

Comment: I don't understand that. Can you explain what you want to do exactly?

Comment: check i have edited my question and updated 2 images, see difference between 2 image, one image is getting cut from left and right sight.

Comment: one image i have loaded from glide and one by fresco, but in fresco image is getting cut.

Comment: I import xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto", after than scaleType is working .

Answer (score 0):

try to set this Programmatically, it's working

```
simpleDraweeView.getHierarchy().setActualImageScaleType(ScalingUtils.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
```